# Collations are not working fine in Solr

Tags: solr, collation, spell-checking, search-suggestion

I am working on **spell checking** in **Solr**. I have implemented **Suggestions** and **collations** in my spell checker component.

```
Most of the time collations work fine but in few case it fails.
```

**Working:**

I tried `query:gone wthh thes wnd`: In this **wnd** doesn't give suggestion **wind** but **collation** is coming **right** = **gone with the wind**, `hits = 117`

**Not working:**

But when I tried `query: gone wthh thes wint`: In this, **wint** does give suggestion **wind** but **collation** is **not coming** right. Instead of **gone with the wind** it gives **gone with the west**, `hits = 1`

And I also want to know what is **hits** in **collations**.

**Configuration:**

```
solrconfig.xml:

<searchComponent name="spellcheck" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">
    <str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">textSpellCi</str>
    <lst name="spellchecker">
      <str name="name">default</str>
      <str name="field">gram_ci</str>
      <str name="classname">solr.DirectSolrSpellChecker</str>
      <str name="distanceMeasure">internal</str>
      <float name="accuracy">0.5</float>
      <int name="maxEdits">2</int>
      <int name="minPrefix">0</int>
      <int name="maxInspections">5</int>
      <int name="minQueryLength">2</int>
      <float name="maxQueryFrequency">0.9</float>
      <str name="comparatorClass">freq</str>
    </lst>
</searchComponent>

<requestHandler name="/spell" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="df">gram_ci</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">default</str>
      <str name="spellcheck">on</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.count">25</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.maxResultsForSuggest">100000000</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.alternativeTermCount">25</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.maxCollations">50</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.maxCollationTries">50</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.collateExtendedResults">true</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="last-components">
      <str>spellcheck</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>

Schema.xml:

<field name="gram_ci" type="textSpellCi" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>

</fieldType><fieldType name="textSpellCi" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
       <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" maxShingleSize="5" minShingleSize="2" outputUnigrams="true"/>
</analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" maxShingleSize="5" minShingleSize="2" outputUnigrams="true"/>
</analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer of my question. After depth reading, I found the logic behind **collations**.

`1) spellcheck.maxCollations:` It just **make collation** candidates to test against the index.

`2) spellcheck.maxCollationTries :` It evaluates the collations that builds at the time of **spellcheck.maxCollations**. If we set the value of `spellcheck.maxCollationTries` **low**, then it gives **better collations** while if we set the value of `spellcheck.maxCollationTries` **high**, then it gives **more collation results**, but it **harms the performance**.

So, By **increasing** the value of `spellcheck.maxCollationTries`, it gives the collation of **gone wthh thes wint** to **gone with the wind** but again I say, it **harms** the performance.

Comment: I want to do spell/query correction functionality. I have 49 GB indexed data where I have applied spellchecker. I want to do same as Google - "did you mean".
Example - If any user types any question/query which might be misspell or wrong typed. I need to give them suggestion like "Did you mean".
Is Solr best for it?